# GUI Compilation

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, windows

guys. I'm trying to compile GUI for Windows as described here https://github.com/monero-project/monero-gui. After execution "make deploy" I'm getting the error (see screenshot). How to fix it? Is there another way to compile it?
[image]

Also tried executing "windeployqt C:/msys64/home/Administrator/monero-gui/build/release/bin/monero-wallet-gui.exe -no-translations -qmldir=C:/msys64/home/Administrator/monero-gui", got error when launching compiled exe (screenshot 2)
[image]

Please help

Comment: Try installing the correct version of Qt

Comment: Which one is correct?

Comment: I'm not sure (mingw-w64-x86_64-qt5 ?) but looks like you've opened a [ticket](https://github.com/monero-project/monero-gui/issues/3041) so hopefully you'll get some advice from the windows gui people.

Comment: I installed mingw-w64-x86_64-qt5

Comment: A work around was provided here: https://github.com/monero-project/monero-gui/issues/3041#issuecomment-674387594

Comment: It's not a workaround for compiling exe